# Passing a function as an argument doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm making a card game where you try to get pairs of 4, each round a player asks another player if they have a certain card value, if they have it then they should hand all of the cards of that value to the player that asked.

In the askPlayer() function I prompt to see which player should receive the question. Then I return whatever the input was.

```
function askPlayer() {
    var askedPlayer = prompt('Which player do you want to ask?');
    return askedPlayer;
}
```

In the askCard() function I take whatever askPlayer() returned and use it in the prompt of askCard().

```
function askCard(player) {
    var whichCard = prompt(player + ', all your:');
    return whichCard;
}
```

However, in an else statement further down in the code I call both these functions, first askPlayer() then askCard() using the returned variable from askPlayer(). This is where the problem comes, when I write it like this it shows the whole function code in the prompt message instead of what the function returned. But when I add parameters like so: `askCard(askPlayer());` it calls the askPlayer again.. What am I doing wrong? Been using this way before and it has worked so I'm confused why it's not working now.

```
else {
    askPlayer();
    askCard(askPlayer);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *call* the function, not just refer to it:

```
function askCard(player) {
    var whichCard = prompt(player() + ', all your:');
    // () here ------------------^^
    return whichCard;
}
```

```js
function askPlayer() {
    var askedPlayer = prompt('Which player do you want to ask?');
    return askedPlayer;
}

function askCard(player) {
    var whichCard = prompt(player() + ', all your:');
    return whichCard;
}
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {
  askCard(askPlayer);
};
```

```html
<button id="btn">Ask</button>
```

---

You've said:

> I call both these functions, first askPlayer() then askCard() using the returned variable from askPlayer().

but then you show this code:

```
askPlayer();
askCard(askPlayer);
```

which doesn't do that. That code calls `askPlayer` and then throws away its return value. Then it calls `askCard` and passes in the `askPlayer` function reference. If you want to use the return value of `askPlayer`, you have to...use the return value of `askPlayer`:

```
var player = askPlayer();
askCard(player);
```

or

```
askCard(askPlayer());
```

and then use your original `askCard`, because your argument isn't a *function*, it's a string:

```
function askCard(player) {
    var whichCard = prompt(player + ', all your:');
    return whichCard;
}
```

```js
function askPlayer() {
    var askedPlayer = prompt('Which player do you want to ask?');
    return askedPlayer;
}

function askCard(player) {
    var whichCard = prompt(player + ', all your:');
    return whichCard;
}
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {
  askCard(askPlayer());
};
```

```html
<button id="btn">Ask</button>
```

Comment: This yields the same result as writing () in the else statement as I explained.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz: No it doesn't. I've added snippets to demonstrate that.

Comment: Oh ye forgot I have to save it in a variable.. Silly. Thanks.